# Как сделать зеркало для сайта?

Tags: ddos, зеркало, сервер

Дело в том, что бывают всякие ситуации: кто-то ддосит, или хостинг падает по какой-то причине, или просто не работает. Как запускать в этом случаи зеркальный сервер? Чтобы если какие-то вдруг неполадки - не вылетало 503, 502, "Невозможно загрузить страницу", и прочих ошибок, а подключалась к другому хостингу, без участия владельца сайта в этом. Можно ли это реализовать? Или как-то по другому может можно сделать? Или сработает просто если указать DNS зоны двух хостингов для домена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две зоны - нет, а вот несколько [А-записей](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS) - можно.

Для того чтобы защита жила постоянно, используют автоматические балансировщики. Самое доступное решение [Round-robin](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS).

Его, на умеренно-платной основе умеет делать [no-ip.org](http://www.noip.com/managed-dns/enhanced-features).

Из личного опыта, скажу, что достаточно неплохо умеет.

Comment: Прочитал прочие вопросы mctrane... Це я зря так практически подошел к вопросу? ))

Comment: Нет, всё норм, просто в администрировании не очень шарю, разбираюсь пока что что это за проекты.